# How to correctly update ListView from BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, listview, backgroundworker

I have a `ListView` control which has about 5000 items in it. I'm using `BackgroundWorker` to search the `ListView` control and find items in it. The problem is that when I find an item I need to change it's `backcolor` and scroll to it in my `ListView`.

My `Backgroundworker` code:

```
private void SearchTrackerList(int column, string text)
    {
            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in ListView_DeviceList.Items)
            {
                if (lvi.SubItems[column].Text.Equals(text))
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        ListView_DeviceList.Items[lvi.Index].EnsureVisible();
                        lvi.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    ));
                    deviceSearchFound = true;
                }   
            }           
    }
```

Everything works as it's supposed to but my invoke which is used to update my `ListView` fires everytime a match is found and this slows down the whole code. What would be a correct way to update my `ListView` control when an item is found?

Comment: Winform or WPF?

Comment: Are you expecting this to find - and thus scroll to - multiple items in the list?

Comment: The Invoke is used so you do not get cross-threading issues.  So there is no other real choice.

Comment: `break;` Or `return;` the loop when a match is found? Right after `deviceSearchFound = true;`

Comment: @dr.null this would be a correct solution for the first match found but there can be multiple matches and I need to find all of them.

Comment: @Vernou Winform

Comment: @Ziema You will get a cross-thread exception if you call this method from the `DoWork` event of the `BackgroundWorker` because you are trying to access an object (`ListView_DeviceList`) from the UI thread. So Its not clear how do you call this method. In fact, you don't need a `BackgroundWorker` to search the ListView. I just did a test with 10,000 items to change the color of each item not only some of them and it was fast enough. For now, call the `EnsureVisible()` method for the LAST match found and not for each. After the `foreach` block.